# Elasticsearch - Lookup value for query score

Tags: elasticsearch, mvel

I am using elasticsearch with a custom script. I need to create a custom score based on another values defined in another index. Let's call this value "ranking". The score should look like this:

```
Math.log(_score * 2) + doc['ranking'].value
```

The ranking is dependent on the provider field in the type that is being scored. My problem is that since then ranking is in another index all together, it doesn't retrieve the value. What is the best way to conduct such a score? Also, how could it be done so that it could cache the results. For example, is there anyway in mvel to retrieve the value based on a redis key-value pair.

Answer (score 1):

1. You must forget about mvel :)
2. You should use Groovy scripting

You could check this link for caching technique https://github.com/imotov/elasticsearch-native-script-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/examples/nativescript/script/LookupScript.java, but it's native java plugin. Though it could be translated to groovy script instance.

Another way (but it depends on your index relations, for example for parent/child), you could use `has_child` query and use `score` field as a transfer block between indexes, but this is too limited.